# HTML table not automatically updating after executing HTTP post

Tags: html, angular, api, post

I created a dummy website for a 'game library' just to teach myself the http POST, GET, PUT and DELETE methods, I have a separate file for my api with 3 'games' in. The post does work when I enter a new game name and click enter nothing happens but when I refresh the page my html table then displays the first three games plus the one I just posted. I would like to have it post and then display it on the table right away rather than having to refresh the page as its abit sloppy in my opinion.

I have tried putting the input box above the table, but I don't really know what else to try.

```html
  <h3>Here is your list of current games in your library</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
   <th>Name</th>
 </tr>
 <tr *ngFor="let game of games">
   <td>{{game.id}}</td>
   <td>{{game.name}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

```js
public games: any = [];
     private url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/games';


 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){
     httpClient.get(this.url).subscribe(response => {
     this.games = response;
     });
 }

createGame(name: HTMLInputElement) {
    let post = {name :  name.value};
    name.value = '';
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers= headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.httpClient.post(this.url, {id: this.games.length + 1,name: post.name }, {headers})
    .subscribe(response => {
         console.log(response)

    })

}
```

I would like the table to auto update when I post a new game to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add newly created game to `games` array inside `createGame` method:

```
this.games.push({id: this.games.length + 1,name: post.name });
```

For `PUT` method you need to find edited item in array and then change its data:

```
let editedGame = this.games.find(game => game.id === UserInputId);
editedGame.name = UserInputName;
```

Comment: thankyou so much that fixed the problem, how would I go about fixing the same issue but for a put request.

Comment: put is for editing game? Could you post your `edit` method?

Comment: let PutURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/games/' + UserInputId;


        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers= headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   
       let game = {
           id : UserInputId,
           name : UserInputName
       }
       

        this.httpClient.put(PutURL, game, {headers})
        .subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response);
            
            
        })

Answer (score 1):

You are not retrieving back the changed data. Once the **POST** call is successful, make a **GET** call to get the updated data.

```
createGame(name: HTMLInputElement) {
    let post = {name :  name.value};
    name.value = '';
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers= headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.httpClient.post(this.url, {id: this.games.length + 1,name: post.name },{headers}).subscribe(response => {
         console.log(response)
         // Subscribe back the changes
         this.httpClient.get(this.url).subscribe(response => {
             this.games = response;
         });
    })

}
```

Another way is to write another function which uses the **GET** call to update the data. You can use that one for initially loading the data as well as updating after new game creation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implements OnInit on your component, see the doc here [https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit]

Your get request should be in the ngOnInit() like this :

```
ngOnInit(){
  httpClient.get(this.url).subscribe(response => {
     this.games = response;
     });
}
```

After creating your new data, call ngOnInit() function and 
your table will be updated.

Comment: @porgo I've been doing it all the time to reload my data, never had a problem with it but it may not be the best way

Comment: @porgo That's correct. `ngOnInit()` is only used for component initialization and refresh purposes. Try not to use it for subsequent calls.

Comment: @ThéoMoulart Thats not a good practice. It won't matter in low scale application. But fails it extensive functional ones.

Comment: @ThéoMoulart maybe you hadnt problems yet. But `ngOnInit` is for component initialization as @Arcteezy says. You can do there more actions than only getting data from backend. And this can create problems for bigger aplications.

Comment: Ok thanks for your advice,
I will not do that anymore

Answer (score 1):

@sammyleighg try like this,

you can update your games list once you have successfully posting your data, just make another http call to your Server.

create a method to simplified logic.

**Component.ts**

```
public games: any = [];
private url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/games';


 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){
   this.getGamesInfo();
 }

 getGamesInfo() {
  this.httpClient.get(this.url).subscribe(response => {
     this.games = response;
   });
 }

createGame(name: HTMLInputElement) {
    let post = {name :  name.value};
    name.value = '';
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers= headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.httpClient.post(this.url, {id: this.games.length + 1,name: post.name }, {headers})
    .subscribe((response: any) => {
         if(response.status == 200) {
            this.getGamesInfo();
         }

    })

}
```

I will recommend to use [**`ngOnInit()`**](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) for making Api calls rather than in **`constructor()`**